# How to use DRF JWT resfresh

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I can generate token，However, after the Web accesses me with the first token, I cannot give a new token

I set it in setting

`'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,`

But I don't know how to get a new one

Please let me know if you need anything else

I thought that after this setting is completed, the token will be changed automatically Medium expiration time，Looks like I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

based on [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/12/19/how-to-use-jwt-authentication-with-django-rest-framework.html) post, you have to do the following:

1. request the token `http post http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/ username=vitor password=123`

   - this returns a access token and a refresh token
2. use the access token to access the site

   - if the access token expires (site returns 403) use the refresh token to get a new valid access token `http post http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/refresh/ refresh=REFRESHTOKEN`

Note that the refresh token can also expire, then you would have to restart the flow.

**EDIT: code snippets**

## install library

```
pip install djangorestframework_simplejwt
```

[docs of the library](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

## settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        ...
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
    ...
}
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework_simplejwt import views as jwt_views

urlpatterns = [
    # Your URLs...
    path('api/token/', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how to provide specific API

Comment: Because he didn't write tokenrefreshview

Comment: i have adjusted the answer with the code snippets ensure that your `settings.py` adds the jwt authentication and that you add the urls to create & refresh the token

Comment: The library I use is the djangorest framework_ JWT，Does this library have the same function

Comment: i suppose the `djangorestframework_simplejwt` should have the same functionality and it's mentioned in the docs of the DRF therefore i would use this one...